# how to hook to monitor sleep event?

Tags: suspend, monitor, events

Is there an event I can hook up to when the monitor is set to sleep? I mean just the monitor DPMS sleep, not the PC sleep/suspend.

My intention is to run a script when the monitor is sent to sleep but the PC is still on.

Similarly is there an event that is triggered when the monitor resumes from sleep?

Answer (score 2):

`xset -q` will tell you whether the monitor is on or off.

Normally, it will tell you "Monitor is On". However, if you turn the monitor off and then execute the command, it will tell you that it is off.

Try it by entering:

`sleep 1; xset dpms force off; sleep 1; xset -q`

(the `sleep` commands are there to prevent X from mixing the order of events up). Then wiggle your mouse to get the screen back.

In a script, doing `$(xset -q|grep Monitor|awk '{print $3;}')` will give you a variable that is either `On` or `Off`.

`X` is a complicated beast, but on my system it works correctly every time.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my question was slightly different. I need to know *when* the monitor is on or off and not *if* it is on or off. Following your example the only way to know the moment the screen goes off is to constantly query xset, which I guess is not optimal. I was wondering if there are some events we can hook to, similarly to acpi events

Comment: OK, perhaps this works for you: the relevant information is stored in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/[some string]/drm/card0/dpms/` . Perhaps you can use [inotify](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man7/inotify.7.html) to track changes in the file.

Comment: Never mind, I can't get that to work myself.  Apparently the relevant file in `/sys/devices` is one of those that are not monitored by `inotify`.

Comment: I mean, there must be a deamon that fires the monitor sleep event, can't we hook to that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a bash script today that may provide a better answer in a week or so. In the meantime I've found this [reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6062dw/how_to_prevent_screen_from_turning_off_when_play/df4uo9j) with a bash script you might use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
jsdev=${1:-"/dev/input/js0"}
getxss() {
    xset q | grep -e 'timeout\:\|Standby\:' \
        | awk '{a[NR]=$1}END{asort(a);print a[1]}' RS=' '
}
tellit() { notify-send "controller xss holder" "${1:-"date"}: $(date +%T)"; }
fin() { tellit "${1:-"bye"}"; exit; }
trap 'fin "sigint recieved"' INT
slt=$((($(getxss)/5)*4)); [ $slt -lt 1 ] && slt=1; w=60
until [[ -e "$jsdev" || $w -lt 1 ]]; do
    t=$(date +%s); f="$(inotifywait -qq -e create --format '%w%f' -t $w "$(dirname $jsdev)")"
    [ "$f" == "$jsdev" ] && break || t=$(($(date +%s)-$t)) && ((w-=$t))
done; [ $w -lt 1 ] && fin "dev not found" && exit
tellit "connected"; while [ -e "$jsdev" ]; do
    read -rn1< <(jstest --nonblock "$jsdev" 2>/dev/null) \
        && [ -e "$jsdev" ] && xset -display :0 s reset dpms force on
    inotifywait -qq -e delete_self --format '%w%f' -t $slt $jsdev 2>/dev/null
done; fin "disconnected"
```