# Which EVENT triggers DPMS to blank out screen

Tags: display, lock-screen, i3-wm

I deinstalled almost everything and set up i3.
I want to use only i3lock and nothing extended
Now I want i3lock to trigger whenever dpms blanks screen out.
The question is, which event is making the screen black.

this question is very similar to [how to hook to monitor sleep event?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683701/how-to-hook-to-monitor-sleep-event) which was never answered